# Open Source MANO (OSM) authorization using Google Cloud Instance

Tags: google-chrome, google-cloud-platform, authorization, ubuntu-16.04

I am working on installing Open Source MANO (OSM) THREE on Google Cloud Instance Ubuntu 16.04.
After typing the command below, terminal has return "DONE" without ERROR.

```
./install_osm.sh
```

And next, in Chrome, try to access(35.231.195.141 is host ip):

```
https://35.231.195.141:8443
```

But  I can't login because the redirect page below is always stalling:(

```
https://10.142.0.4:8009/authorization?response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F10.142.0.4%3A8443%2Fcallback&scope=openid&client_id=cncudWkub3BlbmlkY2xpZW50
```

(10.142.0.4 is internal ip)

Is this web page relevant to the warning on OSM WIKI as below?

It is at https://osm.etsi.org/wikipub/index.php/OSM_Release_THREE

```
Please note that in OSM 3, authentication is performed using OpenIDConnect and OAuth2.0.
An identity provider has been added to the platform and provided as a service in the SO container running on port 8009.
This means both the browser and the UI server components (that run on the SO container) need to be able to access the SO container using identical URIs.
In short, the tuple of scheme://location:port needs to be reachable via both the browser accessing the system and the UI server running on the SO container (e.g. https://10.66.202.206:8009 for a sample deployment).
This means that if your SO container is behind a NAT that cannot reach the public address of the host, authentication and authorization will not be possible and you will not be able to proceed using the UI.
```

How should I get the SO container be authenticated? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As the warning in the wiki said, there is no way to access the UI in this condition, so you should find a by-pass method to use your own machine access the local IP, which SO container is listening.

There are multiple ways to do that:

- Google Cloud VPN, which might be a overkill,
- Set up a VPN server on your Google Cloud Host, then connect your own machine to this VPN server, then you could access the local IP. e.g. you could set up an OpenVPN server on your Cloud Host.

Answer (score 0):

... Or you can try to create a virtual machine with a GUI, like a windows and access. Perhaps you could modify the webserver to use the public ip instead the internal.